# BuildFire SDK widget code breaking on load and causing blocking

Tags: javascript, angular

I have just recently encountered this issue in the last day or so.  Essentially, whenever a plugin is loaded within the SDK, the widget side code is broken.  In the Chrome debugger it shows that there is a ReferenceError: validator is not defined.

This is the callstack for the Reference Error:

```
angular.min.js:102 ReferenceError: validator is not defined
at new <anonymous> (http://app.buildfire.com/app/pages/controllers/authCtrl.js:2:30)
at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:36:315)
at w.instance (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:75:451)
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:58:476
at s (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:7:408)
at A (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:58:459)
at g (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:51:299)
at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:50:415
at link (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:217:512)
at Z (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:70:149) <div id="login" ng-include="'http://app.buildfire.com/app/fragments/auth/auth.html'" class="ng-scope">
```

The at the very end of that snippet you can see reference to http://app.buildfire.com/app/fragments/auth/auth.html.  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but whenever the widget loads and is blocked it looks like this:

[Broken Widget Auth View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqvo.png)

When I follow that link it creates the same broken view.  I'm not sure if that is what is intended or not, but I thought it might be useful.

I also tried pulling down a completely separate copy of the SDK straight from master in the Buildfire/sdk project.  Even running the SDK against the basic MyPlugin project contained in the new SDK yielded the same exact results.  I'm not sure what the cause of this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue as you described it. Looking into it further it looks like a newly required JavaScript file is missing from the latest version of the SDK. As a temporary work around you can add the following line of code to loadScript.js, where the scripts array is set:

```
, this.domain + "app/scripts/framework/validator.js"
```

I suspect this will be fixed soon in the next version of the SDK.

Comment: The SDK was updated today and has the fix in place. [SDK 1.8.1](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/releases/tag/1.8.1)